# Coded UI Test Builder not recognizing buttons on the pop-up window

Tags: coded-ui-tests

When I click the crosshairs icon on the Coded UI Test Builder and drag it over to the pop-up window buttons (Run and Cancel), it is unable to locate and find the Properties of them on the pop-up window.

Does any one know how I can know the properties of the Run button on the pop-up window?
[image]

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using IE. However, that is just to open the windows based application. I get this prompt to run the Java application after which it goes to the Login screen. The application after signing in with username and password is not web based application

Answer (score 0):

That window appears to be a Java window, which is not supported by Coded UI.

You may be able to extend your tests to interact with the Window:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gautamg/2010/01/05/1-introduction-to-coded-ui-test-extensibility/

Alternatively, if you can detect if the window is present, you may be able to emulate the keypresses required to dismiss/approve the window (e.g Enter, or Tab + Enter). Or, if the window's location is predictable, emulate a click at the desired location.